# reloading a particular component based on the data changes in database in angular 2

Tags: angular, angular-components

I came across a problem while working on angular2. I have a component which gets the data from the database using RESTful web service call and displays it on the screen as a table. In the same page I have one more functionality where I can add a row into the table by getting the data from the form and sending it to the rest api's for saving. Here the problem is when I have created a new entry in the table using rest call how to load the new data into component? I should not load the entire page but the part of it where I am displaying the data from db as a table.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post some code that demonstrates what you try to accomplish.

Comment: It's just a scenario that I have to develop. Still I didn't started coding. What I am expecting is "any built in function or property" which will load the data from the database without calling location.reload() function every time when I have done any database insert operation.

Comment: This question is too generic. Please provide a concrete use case. In Angular2 you usually only update the model (component class or service) and bind the view to the model (`{{}}` or `*ngFor`, ...). If you update the model Angular2 updates the view accordingly.

Comment: Thank you Günter Zöchbauer. I just called the method which is getting the data from the db using rest call once again after inserting some data in the DB. so the model has updated and then it is reflected in the View.

Answer (score 0):

The REST service should include the new information in the response, that way for every promise resolved (REST calls) you can add that data to your component's controller scope and expose/display it on the html.

Answer (score 0):

Angular2 will trigger change detection after your XHR request completed. It done by Zone.js which injects in all actions that can trigger data changes: setTimeout/setInterval, XHRRequest, websockets, DOM events and etc.